# 1C Битрикс. Ошибка при работе с сессиями

Tags: битрикс

После установки Битрикс, спустя некоторое время у меня появляется белый экран(работать в Битрикс становится не возможно). Я создал файл вывода ошибок .error.log. Вот, что я получаю session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: C:/tmp) (0). Все требования при установке Битрикс были соблюдены.

```
ost: bitrix.test - LOW_PRIORITY_ERROR - [ErrorException] E_WARNING
session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: C:/tmp) (0)
D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\lib\application.php:303
#0: session_write_close
    D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\lib\application.php:303
#1: Bitrix\Main\Application->terminate
    D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\lib\application.php:276
#2: Bitrix\Main\Application->end
    D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\classes\general\main.php:3489
#3: CAllMain::FinalActions
    D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\include\epilog_after.php:61
#4: require(string)
    D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\include\epilog.php:3
#5: require_once(string)
    D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\footer.php:4
#6: require(string)
    D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\index.php:7
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно настроить путь сессии OpenServer'а

Откройте файл `D:\OSPanel\userdata\config\PHP-ВЕРСИЯ_php.ini`

укажите путь до папки сессии так

```
session.save_path = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp"
```

создайте папку, если нет `D:\OSPanel\userdata\temp`

Если в файле `D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\.settings.php`

или `D:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\php_interface\dbconn.php`

указан другой путь, замените так же `D:/OSPanel/userdata/temp`

Перезапустите OpenServer

Comment: Сделал такую запись, в dbconn.php.  Так правильно? define('BX_SESSION_SAVE_PATH', 'D:\OSPanel\userdata\temp');

Comment: Не подскажете, как в файл .settings php эту папку пописать. Отдельным ключом, или дописать гдет-то. Например 'tmp'=>array(). Или по другому? Спасибо

Comment: Если в файле `.settings.php` или `dbconn.php` путь к сессии не указан, то добавлять ничего не нужно